# spring boot not able to retrieve gridfs

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, gridfs

So I have been trying for hours or even the whole day on how to retrieve my gridfs from the mongodb.

This is how I save it:

```
 DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
        Map<String, Boolean> values = new HashMap<>();

        values.put("boolean", true);

        dbObject.put("tags", tags);
        dbObject.put("description", des);

        Object id = gridFsTemplate.store(file.getInputStream(), String.valueOf(file.getName()), dbObject);
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").is(jwt.extractEmail(token)));

        Update update = new Update();

        if(repository.findByEmail(jwt.extractEmail(token)) == null){
            update.set("gridFsId", Arrays.asList(id.toString()));
        }
        else{
            User user = repository.findByEmail(jwt.extractEmail(token));
            List<String> gridFsId = user.gridFsId;
            gridFsId.add(id.toString());
            update.set("gridFsId", gridFsId);
        }

        template.updateMulti(query, update, User.class);
        values.put("boolean", true);
        return values;
```

and this is how I try to get it:

```
public List<item> get_items(String token){
        User user = repository.findByEmail(jwt.extractEmail(token));
        List<GridFSFile> items = new ArrayList<>();


    }
```

for some reason whenever I try to use GridFSDBFile the whole line is read.

Please help ;)

Comment: Which part of the code given in this question  deals with gridfs? Locate the relevant documentation in the driver you are using, follow it, if you are having trouble link to the documentation you are following and add the relevant code sample to the question.